# Kendo Grid Template For Loop If Else function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My datasource contains nested JSON data. I'm trying to loop through the data find the Attachments field. 
 Then I make a variable for the data field. If the length is zero then display an empty field, else loop through the attachments and display the attachment name. 
 I have reworked everything and I believe the syntax is correct, but it's not displaying the data.

```
# for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) { #
  #var Attach = data[k].get("Attachments"); #

    if (Attach.length == 0) { #
        #=  #
   #} 
    else {#
    for (var i = 0; i < Attach.length; i++) { #
      #= Attach[i].AttachmentName #
   #} 
  #} 
 #}#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like(untested):

```
# for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
      var Attach = data[k].get("Attachments");

      if (Attach.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < Attach.length; i++) { #
              Attach[i].AttachmentName
          #} 
      } 
}#
```

You have way too many #'s...Once you start a #-block you can't end it and then immediately start another as kendo does not like the 2 ## together...just continue the block you are already in until you need to end it to use your literal.

**Edit**

How about this:

```
# for (var k = 0; k < data.attachments.length; k++) { #
                    #: data.attachments[k].name #
          # } #
```

The data passed in to the template is the individual dataItem for the row, not the entire data set. So, you don't need the other loop where you are looping through the row dataset.

Working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/uQuhe

Comment: It worked!! Ah thank you!! This also helped me fix another template issue I was having. Much appreciated!!